# connect in redux without any mapstatetoprops and still getting things as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I see this weird way things have been done in connect in redux and I am having difficulty in understanding as what is being done and how .
Here is the connect code

```
export default connect(({ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }) => {
  let innings = [];
  let matchInfo = null;
  let currentOver = -1;
  let currentPlayer1Id = null;

  if (matchDetails && Object.keys(matchDetails).length) {
    const {
      homeTeam,
      awayTeam,
      tournament,
      gameDateTime,
      matchDescription,
      venue,
      currentInning,
      officials,
      squad,
      toss,
      matchState
    } = matchDetails;
    if (homeTeam && homeTeam.innings && homeTeam.innings.length) {
      homeTeam.innings.forEach(inning => {
        innings.push({
          order: inning.order,
          battingTeamName: inning.battingTeam,
          isCurrentInning: inning.id === currentInning.id
        });
      });
    }
   // some more operations which i deleted as that is not major concern 
  return {
    innings,
    matchInfo,
    currentOver,
    currentPlayer1Id,
    currentPlayer2Id,
    tournamentId,
    squad: squadObj,
    matchState: matchStateStr,
    isFetchingMatchDetail: false,
    routes,
    detailsData: matchDetails
  };
})(withStyles(styles)(withLocale(CricketScore)));
```

I tried to console log inside render method of the component and i see that whatever has been returned can be seen as props .However ,my concern is that from ({ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }) this came .I don't see the term cricketFantasy anywhere in the .js file where this code is .
Also I don't see any mapStateToProps .

Comment: The function passed to connect as parameter is `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: But where did the terms ({ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails }  come from ?Can you break it into small parts ?

Comment: it cames from your redux store: const mapStateToProps = state => // state = { cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }` is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

It relies on `state` containing a `cricketFantasy` property, the value of which is an object with a `matchDetails` property.

Basically it's just a fancy form of:

`const matchDetails = state.cricketFantasy.matchDetails;`

or

`const { matchDetails } = state.cricketFantasy;`

```js
const mapStateToProps = ({ cricketFantasy: { matchDetails } }) =>
  console.log({ matchDetails });

const state = {
  cricketFantasy: {
    matchDetails: "Hello"
  }
};

const mapStateToProps2 = (state) => {
  const matchDetails = state.cricketFantasy.matchDetails;
  console.log({ matchDetails });
};

mapStateToProps(state);
mapStateToProps2(state);
```